# Convert a list of commands into a function

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica

I have made this

```
f[x_] := x - 2
x0 = 999.; imax = 5;
Module[{i, x}, x[0] = x0;
 For[i = 0, i < imax, x[i + 1] = x[i] - f[x[i]]/f'[x[i]];
  Print[x[i]];
  i++]]
```

and am trying to turn this into a newton rhapson function. I need to be able to input the Function F[x],an initial guess,and imax.

Answer (score 3):

A little bit more Mathematica-ish:

```
newt[f_, x0_, imax_] := NestList[# - f@#/f'@# &, x0, imax];
f[x_] := x - 2
x0 = 999; imax = 5; 
newt[f, x0, imax]
(*
-> {999, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}
*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica is that simple:

```
newtonraph = Function[{f,x0,imax},Module[{i,x}, 
                       x[0] = x0;
                       For[i=0, i < imax, x[i+1] = x[i] - f[x[i]]/f'[x[i]];
                         Print[x[i]];
                         i++
                       ];
                      ];
                     ];
```

and call the function:

```
func[t_] = 23 + t + 2*(t^2)
newtonraph[func,10,100]
```

Comment: No, don't teach beginners to use loops in Mathematica, not in cases (like this one) where there are much better (for performance, conciseness, capability) ways, and ways which beginners ought to learn in preference to learning how to write C (or any other imperative language) in Mathematica.

Comment: I was focusing on the "Function" part. I should have corrected his code however, to be more Mathematica-ish, you are right.